# How to bypass the Goggle account password request on a Z353VL ZtE flip phone both touch screen and hard keys

Tags: stock-android

So I have this old ZTE and I can't find a way to bypass the frp I looked all over online and nothing for the touchscreen hard button model like this I just bypassed a galaxy s7 running oreo for a friend so I thought for sure this phone would have a bypass that you can do using the phone itself [image: showing picture of long press on word options in response to below suggested solution]

Comment: I'm sorry but phone was never logged in with my account  furthermore this particular model Exxon using both a touch screen and a dial pad is not very common it might even be impossible for a bypass without connecting to a computer because it also doesn't give mount SD card in the recovery hard reset

Comment: What is the Android version?

Comment: The model is z353vl and it's a ZTE flip phone with both of touch screen and keypad as for the operating system I don't no way of finding that current information when the phone was issued it was Android 5.1.1 lollipop but even on a hard reset bringing up the option for factory reset there is no recovery log option doing truth I have no idea if that would show the operating system being upgraded anytime currently I'm trying to configure a worker profile with Android Enterprise and try to get into a back door that way maybe

Answer (score 0):

I used this method on a old vodafone device i had a long time ago, almost certain its was a Zte.
 Ok when promted to connect with wi fi, you first connect to your network, then type any name in ad alternative network connection, tap and hold the name u just typed.
You wil get a option to share, on the share screen tap and hold gmail,  the "app info" screen will pop up, here you select notifications, go to the last option witch is "more settings", on that screen select the sub menu and go to "manage accounts"

Ok now you should be in your normal settings menu, here you need to open chrome to download files to help you finnish the process, depending the version of Android you have, there are various ways to do this, Mine was a kitkat simply go to applications and launch chrome.
 There is a way with the google app to launch chrome too, tap and hold the google app in the device manager the "app info" screen will appear again go to "notifications" and select "more settings" open the "manage card history" and select chrome.
There are many sites and apps with will assist you from here,

Comment: Well I had not tried that so thanks for taking the time to help but I don't get the share option just select all...cut...copy...paste took a picture but I don't see a method to post but thanks again

Comment: Posted picture in original question